# how to check if a radio button is checked using jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, jquery-validate

I have a radio button called attendance, how do I create an error if either 'yes' or 'no' is NOT selected. Currently the user can submit the form if either button is not selected which i do not want.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script>      
    $( function(){    
            function validate(id){       
                var enabled = ($("input[name='attendance" + id + "']:checked").val() == 'Yes');         
                if(enabled){              
                    //Please select option is selected              
                    if($("#colour" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                 
                    alert('Please make your colourselection');                  
                    return false;             
                    }              
                    //Please select option is selected              
                    if($("#shade" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                  
                        alert('Please select your shade');                  
                        return false;     

                    }   
                }     
                return true;    
            };

            $("input[name^='attendance']").click(function() {  

                var id = this.name.replace('attendance', '');      
                $("#colour" + id + ", #sahde" + id).prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');         
                validate(id);    
            });      
           $("input:submit").click(function(){         
               var retVal = true;
               $.each([1, 2, 3, 4], function(i, val){
                  retVal = (validate(val) && retVal);
               });
                return retVal;   
           }); 
         }); 
    $(document).ready(function(){             
                                   $("input[name=attendance1]:checked").triggerHandler('click'); 

      });    

}); 
    if (!($("input[name='attendance1']:checked").val())) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
    return false;
    }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: I think you may want to look at the Jquery Validation plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation it will allow you to specify a field as required without large amounts of code

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($("input[name='attendance1']:checked").val()) {
       alert('Nothing is checked!');
        return false;
```

you are missing a ( after the if and the statement for $("input[name='attendance1']:checked").val() is when there is a checked value, meaning true, to trigger the alert.

you might want to change how that works with

```
if (!($("input[name='attendance1']:checked").val())) {
       alert('Nothing is checked!');
        return false;
```

so now if there is nothing selected, the alert would trigger

Comment: Thanks Can you check my editted post, I tried it and its still not working.

Comment: the if statement should not be outside the submit function, where i can't see any from your code, you might want to look at this http://api.jquery.com/submit/, take sometime to read it and change your code accordingly or you could look at plugins, like the one suggested by Glenn Slaven

Comment: is my submit function not $("input:submit").click(function(){   ?

Comment: then you should put the if statement inside the $("input:submit").click(function(){ function, returning a retVal of false so the form is not submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to check whether checkbox is checked or not, so there is no need to check value for this just use

```
if ($("input[name='attendance1'].is(":checked")) {
     #your code
}
```

Hope this help..........