# jquery validation - error if no radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 radio buttons for attendance. 'Yes' and 'No'. I want an error if neither is selected and submit button is clicked.

I have tried

```
if (!$("input[name=attendance1]:checked").val()) {
    alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
```

but the error only displays when i log in and not on submit button click

Comment: Are you intercepting the submit call. If you are not, then it will just submit as normal.

Comment: how do i intercept it. have tried     $("input:submit").click(function(){  infront of it

Comment: the answers below explain how to do that....

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check if a radio button is checked using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474742/how-to-check-if-a-radio-button-is-checked-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `<form>` elements, you can do this. If you're submitting from JavaScript using `$.ajax`, try icyrock's answer.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  if (!$("input[name=attendance1]:checked").val()) {
    alert('Nothing is checked!');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I pasted your code but still does not work. Can you check full code @  http://pastebin.com/0ZvQV7dr. thanks

Comment: Thanks, It is a radio box. I have added my form and updated jquery still having issues. http://pastebin.com/jkrMZVcZ

Comment: I don't see a submit button. What error/problem are you getting? Can you make a jsfiddle example that exhibits the problem?

Comment: You had some problems with braces and the form did not have an id. Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/RRDvA/1/ You should format your code better, that was a mess!

Comment: sorry forgot to add the submit but i do have it. When submit is clicked it is not coming up the error. Are all of the } in place correct?

Comment: Are you looking at this? http://jsfiddle.net/RRDvA/3/ It's working for me... I ran it through www.jslint.com and it seems okay.

Comment: yea sorry posted that after you sent the other without updating the page. Awesome yes its working. The problem was that i didnt put the id in the form. oops. thanks appreciate it

Comment: also if i added  2 more radio buttons e.g attendance 2 and attendance 3. would i just list the radio boxes like so: http://pastebin.com/4AhcBHJn

Comment: You can use `input[name^=attendance]` (starts with) or `input[name*=attendance]` (contains)

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate, im new to jquery.  if (!$("input[name*=attendance](1,2,3):checked").val()) {. If there are radio groups?

Comment: The selector `$("input[name*=attendance]")` will return an array of inputs with name attribute containing the string 'attendance.' It's one selector that gets everything for you. `if (!$("input[name*=attendance]:checked").val()) {...}` is all you need.

Comment: that only seems to be doing it for the first radio button (attendance1). If i leave the rest non selected it still submits

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3syk/2/ Shows how to do it. Check that you're using `input[name*=attendance]` and NOT `input[name*=attendance1]`. The `*=` wildcard accounts for any number at the end.

Comment: Yea thats the way i did do it. Can you see with 3 radio buttons http://jsfiddle.net/RRDvA/8/ to show you what i mean. I want it so that if attendance2 and attendance3 are not still non selected it will show error. Currently only if i leave them all there is an error

Comment: So you want to allow `attendance1` to be unselected, but `attendance2` and `attendance 3` must be? `if ($("input[name=attendance2]:checked").length == 0 || $("input[name=attendance3]:checked").length == 0) {...}` The `val()` thing was confusing, checking for `length` is easier to read.

Comment: I have attendance1, attendance 2, attendance3 as shown in jsfiddle. 
These values are submitted to mysql. all 3 attendances HAVE to be selected independently in order for the form to be submitted. if one is left out an error should appear. Hope this is easier to understand.

Comment: You have other errors on the page. Use the console (right-click on the page, choose Inspect Element in Chrome, then click on the console tab). In particular, your `#colour` and `#shade` selectors are not finding anything because they don't exist.

Comment: i have them on my original form but did not copy them over, They are drop down menus. . i was just showing you what i wish to do with the attendance radio buttons. is it possible?

Comment: `if ($("input[name*=attendance]:checked").length < 3) {...}`

Answer (score 4):

You can't just expect to drop code onto a page and have it work ;). Attach the validation function to the [submit<sup>jQuery</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event of the form:

```
$('#formID').submit(function() {
    if (!$("input[name=attendance1]:checked").val()) {
        alert('Nothing is checked!');
        return false; // so form doesn't submit
    }
});
```

Comment: Plus for adding the return false so the form doesn't submit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `beforeSend` - from the docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

you have this:

> beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)Function
>
> A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings maps are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend option will be called regardless of the type of request.

So you can basically alert in the `beforeSend` and then `return false` to abort the submit.

Here's a working example that shows the part you need:

- http://jsfiddle.net/VvHa5/

Hope this helps.